# Finding closures on $\mathbb R$ over a specific topology

Tags: general-topology

I have the following topology over $\mathbb R$
$$ T = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{G\subseteq \mathbb R: \mathbb Q \setminus G \text{ is finite}\} $$
How could I study the closure of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

HINTS: The answers to the following questions are what you need.

- Are there any non-empty open sets that do *not* intersect $\Bbb Q$?
- Is $\Bbb Q$ an open set?

Comment: $\bar Q$ is $\emptyset$, right?

Comment: @AeT.: No, not at all. Can you find a real number that is *not* a limit point of $\Bbb Q$ in this topology?

Comment: But no closed $C$ can contain $\mathbb Q$, since the closed sets are the form $C = A\cup \{r_1,...,r_n\}$ where $A\subseteq \mathbb I$, right?

Comment: @AeT.: $\Bbb R$ is a closed set.

Comment: Okey, I got it, so $\bar{\mathbb Q}= \mathbb R$

Comment: @AeT.: That’s right: $\Bbb Q$ is still a dense set in this topology.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $x\in \mathbb { R }  $ everey open set $ A$ that contains x  contains also infinite points of $\mathbb{Q}$ . The set of irrational numbers is closed, all rational points have some open sets in $\mathbb { Q}.$